# Flink keyBy grouping issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm pretty new to Flink. I have this code that maps, groups, and sums input JSON.

It's very similar to the word count example.

I expected to get `(vacant,1) (occupied,2)`

But, for some reason I'm getting `(occupied,1) (vacant,1) (occupied,2)`

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "{\n" +
                "    \"Port_128\": \"occupied\",\n" +
                "    \"Port_129\": \"occupied\",\n" +
                "    \"Port_120\": \"vacant\"\n" +
                "\n" +
                "}";
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
        StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<String> in = env.fromElements(s);
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> t = 
        in.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> 
            collector) throws Exception {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
                node.elements().forEachRemaining(v -> {
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(v.textValue(), 1));
                });

            }
        }).keyBy(0).sum(1);

        t.print();
        env.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, I get:

```
10/19/2017 11:27:38 Keyed Aggregation -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
(occupied,1)
(occupied,2)
(vacant,1)
10/19/2017 11:28:03 Keyed Aggregation -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to FINISHED
```

Which is slightly different than your output but important. The reason being that the code is outputting the sum of each key as it receives the data, so first it gets the first occupied (outputting 1), then the second (outputting that the sum for this keyed process is now 2), and then sends the vacant to another keyed process and outputs 1. So this seems like the proper output to me.

**EDIT**

Per comment below, here is the code that would give you the desired output:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String s = "{\n" +
      "    \"Port_128\": \"occupied\",\n" +
      "    \"Port_129\": \"occupied\",\n" +
      "    \"Port_120\": \"vacant\"\n" +
      "\n" +
      "}";
  ExecutionEnvironment env =
      ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
  DataSet<String> in = env.fromElements(s);
  AggregateOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> t =
      in.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>>
            collector) throws Exception {
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
          node.elements().forEachRemaining(v -> {
            collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(v.textValue(), 1));
          });

        }
      }).groupBy(0).sum(1);

  t.print();
  env.execute();
}
```

Comment: How can i block it from KeydAggregation each time  and how it`s differant from the word count exemple ?

Comment: You set up a Datatream program. The Flink word count example is a DataSet program. The two behave differently. Data in a stream is processed as it is received through the pipeline, thus why it processes on each element that goes through. I'll update the answer with a change to your code that is using the DataSet code like the wordcount example. If you run it you will get the output you expect.

Comment: now i got it,
 my mistake was i  use stream and not dataset